# sql server - selecting top x rows by group

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem that I've wasted way too much time playing with.  It can be simplified to something like:

- Platform: SQL Server
- you have a table with age and zipcode
- list the top 5 oldest people in each zipcode

I can see how to do it with cursors, but is there a way with top and group by to achieve this?

All inputs appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT *
           ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY zipcode ORDER BY Age DESC) rn
      FROM TableName
     )A
WHERE RN <= 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ROW_NUMBER analytic function

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM
 ( SELECT name, 
    age, 
    zipcode,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER          
    ( PARTITION by zipcode 
       order by age desc) 
    as seq
   ) T
  Where T.seq <=5
```